# How to add one or more form by a button and remove it by another button by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

i want to add one or more form by a button and remove it by another button by javascript. press one time that button create a form again press that ,then it create same form  by one button.
and i can able to insert their values into the database.

Comment: Did you have sample of code ? It's better for us to give you the right help

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please note that Stackoverflow is not a programming service, it's a community to help programmers with specific problems that they encounter. Please attempt to write your own code, and then post the code if you have any problem(s).

Comment: Need code or something you have tried already ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow arpit. Please go through the article on how to ask a good question. The question should be apparently a constructive and should contain atleast some of the code you've tried out. 

Please read the [guideline][1] to understand more about the topic.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = "2";
  
    $("#addButton").click(function () {
    
 if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
 }   
  
 var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
      .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
        
 newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label style="margin-right:5.9%">Nature Of Income '  +  ' : </label>' +'<input type="text" name="NatureIncome' +   
       '" id="textbox'   + '" value="" ><br>' + '<br><label style="margin-right:10.2%">Total Amount' + ': </label>'+'<input type="text"  name="TotalAmount' +   
       '" id="textbox'   + '" value="" ><br><hr style="border: 1px solid black;">' );
            
 newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

    
 counter++;
     });

     $("#removeButton").click(function () {
 if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }   
        
 counter--;
   
        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
   
     });
  
  });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#add_button").click(function(){
  var intial_field = $(this).data("intial");
  var content = '<div id="input_'+intial_field+'"><input type="text" name="user_name[]" /><button id="remove_btn" data-remove="'+intial_field+'">X</button></div>';
  $("#recurssion_container").append(content);
  $(this).data("intial",intial_field+1);
});
$(document).on("click","#remove_btn",function(){
  var remove_element = $(this).data("remove");
  $("#input_"+remove_element).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="add_button" data-intial="0">+ Add</button>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<div id="recurssion_container"></div>
<input type="text" name="user_name[]" />
<button type="submit" name="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["save"])){
    $user_name_array = $_POST["user_name"];
    foreach($user_name_array as $user_name){
        if($user_name!=""){
            #Put your insert query here
            #Please refer how to save data to database https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You can also limit the number of fields adding by checking variable intial_field

Comment: i want to insert every row data into database plz tell me how to do it